# Shiny: Conditional Panel and Conditional List of checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, facet-wrap

I want to create a shiny app for plotting the most recent pollstR charts of US presidential primaries. Users should be able to select a Party (Dem or Rep), the Candidates and the states, where the primaries (or Caucusus) took place.

I have three problems:

1. Based on the selected party (Dem or Rep), users should get the next checkboxGroupInput, where only the Democratic or Republican candidates appear. I try to solved that with a conditionalPanel. However, I cannot use "Candidate" twice as a name for the Widget (later in the server.R I need input$Candidate). How can I solve that?
2. Based on the selected party (again Dem or Rep), users should get a list of all states, where primaries and caucusus took place up to now. At the moment, I am listing all US states, which I defined before (and hence I get errors, if I want to plot the results of states, where no polls are available). Is there a way to get the list of states from the dataset, which is generated in the server.R part (it is called polls$state there, but I cannot use it, because the ui.R does not now "polls").
3. I plot the results as bar-charts with ggplot and the facet_wrap function (with two columns). The more states I choose, the smaller the plots get. Is there a way to set the height of the plots and insert a vertical scrollbar in the main panel?

Here is the code for the UI:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("2016 Presidential primaries"),

    sidebarLayout(position = "right",
            sidebarPanel(
                    helpText("Choose between Democratic (Dem) and Republican (Rep)
                             Primaries and Caucuses:"),

                    selectInput("party", 
                                label = "Dem or Rep?",
                                choices = c("Dem", "Rep",
                                selected = "Dem")),

                    conditionalPanel(
                            condition = "input.party == 'Dem'",
                            checkboxGroupInput("Candidate", label = h4("Democratic Candidates"), 
                                               choices = list("Clinton" = "Clinton", "Sanders" = "Sanders"),
                                               selected = NULL)),

                    conditionalPanel(
                            condition = "input.party == 'Rep'",
                            checkboxGroupInput("Candidate", label = h4("Republican Candidates"), 
                                               choices = list("Bush" = "Bush", "Carson" = "Carson", "Christie" = "Christie",
                                                              "Cruz" = "Cruz", "Kasich" = "Kasich", "Rubio" = "Rubio",
                                                              "Trump" = "Trump"),
                                               selected = NULL)),

                    checkboxGroupInput("state",
                            label = "Select State",
                            choices = states,
                            inline = TRUE,
                            selected = NULL)
            ),

            mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")), 
                            tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
                    )
            )


    )
))
```

And here the code for the server.R:

```
### getting and cleaning the data for the shiny app-----------------------------

# load pollstR-package to get Huffpost opinion polls
require(pollstR)

# load dplyr and tidyr for data wrangling
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

# load ggplot2 for plotting
require(ggplot2)

# download 2016 GOP presidential primaries
repPoll <- pollstr_charts(topic='2016-president-gop-primary', showall = TRUE)

# extract and combine columns needed
choice <- repPoll$estimates$choice
value <- repPoll$estimates$value
election <- repPoll$estimates$slug
party <- repPoll$estimates$party

rep.df <- data_frame(election, choice, value, party)


# extract and combine slug and state info to add list of US state abbreviations
election <- repPoll$charts$slug
state <- repPoll$charts$state

r.stateAbb <- data_frame(election, state)

# join both data frames based on slug
rep.df <- left_join(rep.df, r.stateAbb, by = "election")

## download 2016 DEM presidential primaries
demPoll <- pollstr_charts(topic='2016-president-dem-primary', showall = TRUE)

# extract and combine columns needed
choice <- demPoll$estimates$choice
value <- demPoll$estimates$value
election <- demPoll$estimates$slug
party <- demPoll$estimates$party

dem.df <- data_frame(election, choice, value, party)

# extract and combine slug and state info to add list of US state abbreviations
election <- demPoll$charts$slug
state <- demPoll$charts$state

d.stateAbb <- data_frame(election, state)

# join both data frames based on slug
dem.df <- left_join(dem.df, d.stateAbb, by = "election")

# combine dem and rep datasets
polls <- bind_rows(dem.df, rep.df)

polls$party <- as.factor(polls$party)
polls$state <- as.factor(polls$state)
polls$choice <- as.factor(polls$choice)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

        df <- reactive({
                polls %>% filter(party %in% input$party) %>% filter(choice %in% input$Candidate) %>%
                        filter(state %in% input$state)
        })

       # generate figures
        output$plot <- renderPlot({
                validate(
                        need(input$party, "Please select a party"),
                        need(input$Candidate, "Please choose at least one candidate"),
                        need(input$state, "Please select at least one state")
                )
                p <- ggplot(df())
                p <- p + geom_bar(aes(x = choice, weight = value, fill = choice),
                                  position = "dodge", width=.5) 

                # colorize bars based on parties        
                if (input$party == "Dem")
                        p <- p + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues", direction = -1)
                if (input$party == "Rep")
                        p <- p + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Reds", direction = -1)

                # add hlines for waffle-design
                p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept=seq(0, 100, by = 10), col = 'white') +
                        geom_text(aes(label = value, x = choice, y = value + 1), position = position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
                        # facet display
                        facet_wrap( ~ state, ncol = 2) +
                        # scale of y-axis
                        ylim(0, 100) + 
                        # delete labels of x- and y-axis
                        xlab("") + ylab("") +
                        # blank background and now grids and legend
                        theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
                              panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
                              panel.background = element_blank(), legend.position = "none")
                print(p)    
        }

        )

        # Generate a table view of the data
        output$table <- renderTable({
                polls %>% filter(party %in% input$party) %>% filter(choice %in% input$Candidate) %>%
                        filter(state %in% input$state)
        })

}
)
```

Comment: The first two issues can be resolved using `renderUI` on the server code. You can look up some examples from the official shiny website. Basically you observe for selections in `party`, and then dynamically render a candidate checkbox for that party. You can also use `renderUI` to render a checkboxgroup for states, since it's in the server code, you do have access to `polls`.

Comment: I tried to do that, but the widget is not displayed in the UI :-(

Comment: If you post your code both server and ui, I'll help have a look.

Comment: ok, thank you! I will post the original server.R code, so that the whole ui.R and the questions make sense.

Comment: 1. Well, you can't use the same identifier for the same thing. If you make a Shiny module, you can, but you still need to use the `NS()` and `ns()` functions for namespacing. 2. One way to do this is to have some sort of filtering function based on some sort of table where the states are the columns and their attributes are the row, like whether they had a primary. Then, you can do subseting and filtering based off of that row. 3. I don't know about vertical scrolling, but another approach is to generate graphs on the fly as the user selects more states. Reactivity is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for problem 1 and 2:

In `ui.R`, replace `conditionalPanel` and `checkboxGroupInput` with

```
  uiOutput('candidates'),
  uiOutput('states')
```

In `server.R`, add the following code before `df <- reactive({....`. Note that you need to change some of your `input$Candidate` code to lower case.

```
  observeEvent(input$party, {
    output$candidates <- renderUI({
      checkboxGroupInput(
        "candidate",
        ifelse(input$party == 'Dem', "Democratic Candidates", "Republican Candidates"),
        as.vector(unique(filter(polls,party==input$party)$choice))
      )
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$candidate, {
    output$states <- renderUI({
      states_list <- as.vector(unique(filter(polls, party==input$party & choice==input$candidate)$state))
      checkboxGroupInput(
        "state",
        "Select state",
        # Excluding national surveys
        states_list[states_list!="US"]
      )
    })
  })
```

For problem 3, change the `df` `reactive` to `observe`, and then set plot height depending on how many states selected. Also change this line `p <- ggplot(df)`

```
  observe({      
    df <- polls %>% filter(party %in% input$party) %>% filter(choice %in% input$candidate) %>% filter(state %in% input$state)
    height <- ceiling(length(input$state) / 2) * 200
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      #Your plot code
    }, height=height)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. I still have three problems: 1) I get the list of all Candidates, but I do want to narrow it to Clinton and Sanders and the Democratic side and to Trump, Cruz, Rubio, Kasich and Carson on the Republication side. 2) At the moment, I only get those states, where all candidates selected participated. So in the extreme case, only a view states remain, if a lot of candidates are selected. 3) there are not plots. I get the error message: "Argument x is missing"

Comment: Ok, I solved problem no. 3: I had to delete the () in p <- ggplot(df())

Comment: But you really answered the question. So I set it to solved. Thank you so much!!! reducing the list of Candidates can easily be done by filtering them in the server.R part before the shinyServer function.